# EF Code First 4.3 DbContext Lifecycle?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-4.3

I've searched but haven't found much on this topic. Has anyone seen a concise "order of operations" for the DBContext, including stuff like instantiation, validation, saving, etc? I'm mainly curious because while using LINQPad with my EF 4.3 Code First context, it runs two queries before any of my own. One has to do with the migration history which I understand is because we're using EF Migrations and it's attempting to see if it needs to auto-update, and another is for the EdmMetadata table which I don't understand since it sounds like that's not necessary if we're using EFMigrations.

My lack of understanding of why the one query is called makes me wonder if there are other parts of the DBContext's lifecycle that I am unaware of that might be useful to understand/override. Thanks in advance!

Comment: (sorry for my bad english) Here are some info: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/01/13/ef-4-3-beta-1-what-happened-to-that-edmmetadata-table/ , EF 4.3 has the abillity to use the EdmMetadata to test for model compatibility - although, as you said, if you are using Migrations probably it should not use it at all. But i am more curious about how did you got linqpad to work with EF 4.3... i'm getting a "could not load EntityFramework 4.1" error when trying to open my context assembly :(

Comment: I think it only works in the latest beta version of LINQPad.

Comment: I think that is what I am using, version 4.38.03 ... just to be sure, are you compiling your project with EntityFramework 4.3.0.0?

Comment: Yup. Which LINQPad driver are you selecting? I'm using EF DBContext POCO (4.1/4.2) and it's working fine.

Comment: I am selecting the "Entity Framework DbContext POCO (4.1/4.2)" also...  must be another problem here, will take a look at it, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Put your connection string in a dummy web.config, with the connection string as the only item in the web.config. I was able to get EF 4.3 to work in Linqpad that way.

Answer (score 0):

The query for EdmMetadata is for compatibility reasons. EF 4.1 did not have migrations. To be able to figure out whether model changed or not the EdmMetadata table was used. Let's say you developed an app using EF 4.1 app and you moved to EF 4.3 but you did not change the model. In this case there is no need to run migrations, throw exceptions or touch the database since your model has not changed. The call to the EdmMetadata table is just to be able to handle this situation gracefully and avoid throwing or touching the database if it is not needed.
I don't think there were any other changes of this kind in EF 4.3.